# I am planning to use GetFieldValueAsHtml in CSOM world and I am not able to find that method for FieldMultiLineText class

Tags: client-object-model

I am planning to use GetFieldValueAsHtml in CSOM world and I am not able to find that method for FieldMultiLineText class

Let us know how to get this method in the CSOM world.

But that method is available for SPFieldMultiLineText and not for FieldMultiLineText

Comment: actually there is such property in SP.ListItem, called `get_fieldValuesAsHtml()` (JSOM).

Answer (score 1):

[List Item class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem(v=office.14).aspx) exposes [ListItem.FieldValuesAsHtml Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.fieldvaluesashtml(v=office.14).aspx), the following example demonstrates how to retrieve `FieldValuesAsHtml` property for a `List Item`:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{ 
     var web = ctx.Web;
     var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx");
     var listItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
     ctx.Load(listItem, i=>i.FieldValuesAsHtml);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     var fieldVals = listItem.FieldValuesAsHtml;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using `ListItem.get_item("richTextField")` will return the value of your field as HTML -- that is how sharepoint stores multiline values.